# Xcode's theme for TextMate

Tags: xcode, textmate, themes

I'd like the default theme of Xcode but for TextMate.

Is there anyone who knows where I could find this?

Comment: If you created this theme, I'd be interested in a copy of it :)

Comment: How about anything for the dusk theme? I have been looking everywhere for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always just make it yourself, duplicate one of the TextMate themes and then apply the font styles from Xcode to the textmate theme. It won't take too long and will let you fix the bits that you think are broken!

Comment: That's a nice idea! Do you know any good guides about creating a TextMate theme? Thanks!

Comment: Personally I'd just head into the textmate preferences fonts and colours, click on the drop-down scroll to the bottom, `Edit Theme List…` click on a theme and then click the ++ symbol - this'll create a duplicate that you can edit at your hearts desire

Answer (score 9):

I just [created it,](http://github.com/earcar/xcode-default.tmtheme) check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't get Paolino or El's themes to install in TextMate 2.0, I've created a new Xcode Default theme from scratch here:

https://github.com/jrodatus/xcodedefault-tmtheme-ng

[image: Xcode-syntax][image: TextMate-syntax]

#### Installation

- Theme extension must be ".tmTheme" (exactly)
- Double-click to install in TextMate, select "Themes" bundle when prompted
- View->Theme->Xcode Default
- View->Font->Show Fonts...: Menlo Regular 10.3 or 10.5
- TextMate->Preferences->Projects->Open files on single click
- Show file browser on: Left side

#### Extra

To change the selection color from orange, change the hex color code after the "selection" key in the tmTheme file.

To suppress tab creation when clicking on a file in the browser:

- Method 1) Hold the Option key every time you click on a file.
- Method 2) Clone the TextMate [repository](https://github.com/textmate/textmate) and edit `textmate/Frameworks/DocumentWindow/src/DocumentWindowController.mm`, replacing the occurences of `OakIsAlternateKeyOrMouseEvent()` with `YES`, and rebuild.
- Method 3) If you don't want to install the build prerequisites, you can patch the binary directly. See GitHub [README](https://github.com/jrodatus/xcodedefault-tmtheme-ng/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: should have noted, this theme was made to match C/C++ coloring. HTML coloring looks kind of weird.